# Do dictionaries keep track of the point in time where a item was assigned?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was coding a High Scores system where the user would enter a name and a score then the program would test if the score was greater than the lowest score in high_scores. If it was, the score would be written and the lowest score, deleted. Everything was working just fine, but i noticed something. The `high_scores.txt` file was like this:

```
PL1 50
PL2 50
PL3 50
PL4 50
PL5 50
```

PL1 was the first score added, PL2 was the second, PL3 the third and so on. Then I tried adding another score, higher than all the others (PL6 60) and what happened was that the program assigned PL1 as the lowest score. PL6 was added and PL1 was deleted. That was exactly the behavior I wanted but I don't understand how it happened. Do dictionaries keep track of the point in time where a item was assigned? Here's the code:

```
MAX_NUM_SCORES = 5

def getHighScores(scores_file):
    """Read scores from a file into a list."""

    try:
        cache_file = open(scores_file, 'r')
    except (IOError, EOFError):
        print("File is empty or does not exist.")
        return []
    else:
        lines = cache_file.readlines()
        high_scores = {}

        for line in lines:
            if len(high_scores) < MAX_NUM_SCORES:
                name, score = line.split()
                high_scores[name] = int(score)
            else:
                break

        return high_scores

def writeScore(file_, name, new_score):
    """Write score to a file."""

    if len(name) > 3:
        name = name[0:3]

    high_scores = getHighScores(file_)

    if high_scores:
        lowest_score = min(high_scores, key=high_scores.get)
        if new_score > high_scores[lowest_score] or len(high_scores) < 5:
            if len(high_scores) == 5:
                del high_scores[lowest_score]

            high_scores[name.upper()] = int(new_score)                  
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        high_scores[name.upper()] = int(new_score)

    write_file = open(file_, 'w')
    while high_scores:
        highest_key = max(high_scores, key=high_scores.get)
        line = highest_key + ' ' + str(high_scores[highest_key]) + '\n'
        write_file.write(line)
        del high_scores[highest_key]

    return 1

def displayScores(file_):
    """Display scores from file."""

    high_scores = getHighScores(file_)

    print("HIGH SCORES")
    if high_scores:
        while high_scores:
            highest_key = max(high_scores, key=high_scores.get)
            print(highest_key, high_scores[highest_key])
            del high_scores[highest_key]
    else:
        print("No scores yet.")

def resetScores(file_):
    open(file_, "w").close()
```

Comment: Can you show us what `high_scores`'s value is after you call `high_scores = getHighScores(file_)`? I want to see how the method handles the data.

Comment: It seems like using a `dict` is unnecessary in this situation, and in fact makes things harder. Why not use a `list` of `(name,value)` tuples instead?

Comment: @Jovito why does `"PL6"` result in 50? Shouldn't it be 60? And I am confused, because you have a dictionary with square brackets. This is impossible. A list with colons does not exist, at least for python 3.x, which I tried it on. It returns a syntax error.

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome Sorry, here it is. Before adding PL6: `high_scores = {"PL1" : 50, "PL2" : 50, "PL3" : 50, "PL4" : 50, "PL5" : 50}` After adding PL6: `high_scores = {"PL6" : 60, "PL2" : 50, "PL3" : 50, "PL4" : 50, "PL5" : 50}`

Comment: I really think that you should stick with a list of tuples rather than a dictionary. As the user below said, dictionaries are unordered and are not meant to be used this way. Sorting a list of tuples based by their second elements is much easier than what you are doing. When you do `key = high_scores.get`, it is random each time, and therefore unpredictable. I think that could be the cause of this behavior. Even if that is not it, I recommend strongly to use a list of tuples, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The results you got were due to arbitrary choices internal to the `dict` implementation that you cannot depend on always happening. (There is a subclass of `dict` that does keep track of insertion order, though: `collections.OrderedDict`.) I believe that with the current implementation, if you switch the order of the PL1 and PL2 lines, PL1 will probably still be deleted.

Comment: But I tested it several times and the items were replaced in order ):

Comment: That's the annoying thing about arbitrary behavior - it frequently follows patterns, but they can break at any moment, and if you relied on something that looked predictable, you'll get weird bugs. Try putting random garbage as the names and see what happens.

Comment: Actually the names i used were random. "PL1, PL2, PL3..." was just a way to convey order.

Comment: Just tried it again and it seems you're right. But then, how `min()` decides what score is the lowest?

Comment: Another arbitrary decision. Things with the same key are supposed to be equivalent, so it doesn't really matter which one it picks. I don't know how the function actually makes its choice. My guess is that it keeps the first one it sees, but your code shouldn't rely on the decision being consistent, since the Python developers are free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, the order of items in the dictionary is "up to the implementation".

This answer is more a comment to your question, "how `min()` decides what score is the lowest?", but is much too long and format-y for a comment. :-)

The interesting thing is that both `max` and `min` can be used this way.  The reason is that they (can) work on "iterables", and dictionaries are iterable:

```
for i in some_dict:
```

loops `i` over all the keys in the dictionary.  In your case, the keys are the user names.  Further, `min` and `max` allow passing a `key` argument to turn each candidate in the iterable into a value suitable for a binary comparison.  Thus, `min` is pretty much equivalent to the following python code, which includes some tracing to show exactly how this works:

```
def like_min(iterable, key=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    result = it.next()
    if key is None:
        min_val = result
    else:
        min_val = key(result)
    print '** initially, result is', result, 'with min_val =', min_val
    for candidate in it:
        if key is None:
            cmp_val = candidate
        else:
            cmp_val = key(candidate)
        print '** new candidate:', candidate, 'with val =', cmp_val
        if cmp_val < min_val:
            print '** taking new candidate'
            result = candidate
    return result
```

If we run the above on a sample dictionary `d`, using `d.get` as our `key`:

```
d = {'p': 0, 'ayyy': 3, 'b': 5, 'elephant': -17}
m = like_min(d, key=d.get)
print 'like_min:', m

** initially, result is ayyy with min_val = 3
** new candidate: p with val = 0
** taking new candidate
** new candidate: b with val = 5
** new candidate: elephant with val = -17
** taking new candidate
like_min: elephant
```

we find that we get the key whose value is the smallest.  Of course, if multiple values are equal, the choice of "smallest" depends on the dictionary iteration order (and also whether `min` actually uses `<` or `<=` internally).

(Also, the method you use to "sort" the high scores to print them out is O(n<sup>2</sup>): pick highest value, remove it from dictionary, repeat until empty.  This traverses n items, then n-1, ... then 2, then 1 => n+(n-1)+...+2+1 steps = n(n+1)/2 = O(n<sup>2</sup>).  Deleting the high one is also an expensive operation, although it should still come in at or under O(n<sup>2</sup>), I think.  With n=5 this is not that bad (5 * 6 / 2 = 15), but ... not elegant. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/python-tree-and-heap-comparison/ is about.

Short version: Get the treap module, which works like a sorted dictionary, and keep the keys in order.  Or use the nest module to get the n greatest (or least) values automatically.

collections.OrderedDict is good for preserving insertion order, but not key order.